# Can't remove ceph xattrs on CephFS on Linux

Tags: linux, ceph, xattr

I had set xattrs for quota limits on CephFS

```
$ setfattr -n ceph.quota.max_bytes -v 1100000000  /mnt/cephfs/data/
```

I can get value of this attribute

```
$ getfattr -n ceph.quota.max_bytes /mnt/cephfs/data/
getfattr: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: mnt/cephfs/data/
ceph.quota.max_bytes="1100000000"
```

But then I try to remove quota, I had

```
$ setfattr -x ceph.quota.max_bytes /mnt/cephfs/data/
setfattr: /mnt/cephfs/data/: No such attribute
```

How can I remove this xattr?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posting is not a good idea (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747936/cant-remove-ceph-xattrs-on-linux/749300#749300). But here's the same answer:

The way to remove the quota is not to use `setfattr -x` but set the value to 0:

```
setfattr -n ceph.quota.max_bytes -v 0 /mnt/cephfs/data/
```

Check out the [docs](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/cephfs/quota/) for more information.